# Is there a way to style a specific element inside a div but not affect all elements in general?

Tags: html, css

Sample code

```html
<head>
  <title>Albert</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"> 
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Hello</h1>
  <div class="">
    <h1> I'm Albert</h1>
    <p> a physicist</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to be able to write in the `css/styles.css` something like

```scss
div{
  background-color: #E4F9F5;
        
  h1 {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

Of course, the above does not work.

My question: Is it possible to define select a specific element inside a div so that only that element inside of the div is changed and not every element is changed?

Comment: you clould alsow just use a class on the h1 tag ```<h1 class="myclass">I'm Albert</h1>``` and use this in the css file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're *close*, the CSS structure just isn't correct.  Tools like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) can do this with the syntax you're attempting and then output CSS to be used by the browser.  In plain CSS you'd use a specific selector instead of nesting the style rules.  For example, to target `<h1>` elements as a direct child of `<div>` elements:

```css
div {
    background-color: #E4F9F5;
}

div > h1 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div>
    <h1>I'm Albert</h1>
    <p>a physicist</p>
</div>
```

Or perhaps to target any `<h1>` that's a descendant of any `<div>`:

```css
div {
    background-color: #E4F9F5;
}

div h1 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div>
    <span><h1>I'm Albert</h1></span>
    <p>a physicist</p>
</div>
```

There are a variety of options available.  The overall point is that the structure isn't nested in the CSS syntax, instead its a separate style rule with a more targeted selector.

Comment: It must not necessarily be a direct child

Comment: @tacoshy: Fair point, I've updated with another example as well.

Comment: Also interesting: The [CSS Nesting Module](https://w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/), allowing for nesting syntax in the future (maybe). Keep an eye on its status!

Comment: @OskarGrosser I'm sure that David as any serious Senior Dev knows that. However, you must also keep productive use in mind. Even if a rendering engine implemented this, then you still can't use it. The majority of the user does not update the browser on a regular basis. And you shouldn't lock out users with older or non-compatible browsers. So we are still far away from it same as with the `.has` selector that was released last year. Firefox and Opera Mini are not supported yet which would louk out a large portion of potential users.

Comment: @tacoshy The answer mentions nesting syntax in SASS, so mentioning a (potentially future) native syntax seemed fitting. The comment was not meant purely for David, but _anyone_ visiting this answer, which includes even not so "serious Senior Dev"s.